# How to make bookmarked tabs to have bookmark icon?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, browser-tabs

In chrome I am opening a lot 50-100 links and then bookmarking them all, but want to remove already bookmarked ones from opened so that I would bookmark only ones which are not bookmarked yet.

How to make bookmarked tabs to have bookmark icon?

Comment: Questions seeking product, service, or learning material recommendations are off-topic because they become outdated quickly and attract opinion-based answers. Instead, describe your situation and the specific problem you're trying to solve. Share your research.

Comment: @LPChip so then not even to try to find currect solution while not outdated or still maybe none or only one exists, if is findable if made? If other become outated, then this one still has not even one solution. Im updating description of question.